# Are multiple joins on the same table possible?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a question about getting data from a table with multiple joins.
Table 1 holds the information (name and amount) and table 2 contains the combinations.
A row in table 2 contains the id's which correspond to the ID's from table 1.

I try to get the information out of table 1 based on the corresponding id's in table 2.

**Table1**

```
Id | Name   | Amount
--------------------
 4 | Test 1 |     50
 5 | Test 2 |     60
 6 | Test 3 |     70
 7 | Test 4 |     80
```

**Table2**

```
id | PriceId | MaterialId | ServiceId
-------------------------------------
 1 |       4 |          5 |         6
 2 |       4 |          5 |         7
```

**Query**

To get an idea what I try to reach:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 a 
LEFT JOIN Table2 b ON a.Id = b.PriceId
LEFT JOIN Table2 c ON a.Id = c.MaterialId
LEFT JOIN Table2 d ON a.Id = d.ServiceId
GROUP BY a.Id
```

So I try to get the name and amount from table 1 corresponding with the Id's in table 2, Thus:

When I select everything from Table 2 with **ID 1** then I try to get the following:

```
Table 2 with ID 1: PriceId = 4, MaterialId = 6, ServiceId = 6
Table 1: Test 1, Test 2, Test 3
```

Because PriceId 4 is corresponding with Test 1, and MaterialID 6 is corresponding with Test 2 etc etc.

Hopefully above is clearly. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: yes possible and you have already updated an example, share what issue you are facing.

Comment: Please specify your exact desired output.

Comment: I am sorry for my unclear question. Firstly the query didn't gave all results (only test1 and test2) and after some modifications it gave the results on one row (which is not desirable).
The solution is your answer, XL ant. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are approaching it from the wrong direction. What you really want is:

```
SELECT t2.PriceId AS PriceId, 
    t2.ServiceId AS ServiceId, t1p.Name AS PriceName, 
    t1m.Name AS MaterialName, t1s.Name AS ServiceName
FROM Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1p ON t2.PriceId = t1p.Id
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1m ON t2.MaterialId = t1m.Id
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1s ON t2.ServiceId = t1s.Id
```

- See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87d09/8).

Comment: @XLAnt thanks for the fiddle. Couldn't get the site to work when posting my answer.

Comment: Perfect X.L.Ant! I did indeed approached it wrong because my first query gave the results on one row.
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use that way ... 
See my example :

```
select * from movies 
 inner join relationship as r1 on movies.id=r1.movie_id 
inner join relationship as r2 on movies.id=r2.movie_id 
where r1.Taxonomy_id ="xyz" 
and r2.Taxonomy_id="abc"
 GROUP BY movies.id
```

This will work for you. I had done this in one of my project

Comment: Thanks Yo Yo for your reply, I am using XL ant's query. That solved my question as well.

Comment: Thats great Maurice !!